# Change label background color on focusing Check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a check box which is placed inside the label control. I need to change the label background color on focus a checkbox.

Yes

I have seen source code for Textbox as follows:

```
input:focus + label {background-color: red;}
```

I have tried above code with checkbox but for checkbox not working.

```
input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label {background-color: red;}
```

Please help me on this

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6rxWf/127/)

Comment: Is this what you want ? : http://jsfiddle.net/6rxWf/128/

Comment: `+` in CSS is for next sibling element

Comment: @A.Wolff yes but I will have checkbox within label control

Comment: @Vignesh That means it will be a child, not a sibling.

Comment: @Vignesh And then what is expected behaviour? If checkbox is child of label, it isn't a sibling

Comment: @A.Wolff My expected behavior is Checkbox would be child of lable

Comment: @A.Wolff If + in CSS for next sibling element means then what would i use to previous sibling element

Comment: @Vignesh There is nothing like that in CSS

Comment: @a.wolff is there any easy way to achieve this in simply by css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input is a child of the label there is no CSS selector that can affect / select it.

Using Jquery, however, it is a simple matter.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').focus(function () {
        $(this).parents('label').addClass('focused');
    });

    $('input').blur(function () {
        $(this).parents('label').removeClass('focused');
    });
});
```

```css
label {
    float:left;
}
.focused {
    outline:none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 240, 255, 0.4);
    background-color : rgba(0, 240, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="chkYesIsSubPropofferedSale">Check
    <input id="chkYesIsSubPropofferedSale" type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

Note: My JQ skills are minor so I'm sure this can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer given by Paulie_D and the fiddle provided by Alexander - I've come up with the [following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rxWf/127/)

It uses the jQuery [hover event](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to attach and remove a class from a label that's the parent of a checkbox - hopefully this will be of some use to you. The jQuery in question is as below:

```
$('.checkBoxClass').hover(
  function()
  { 
     $(this).parent('label').addClass('focused');
  },
  function()
  { 
     $(this).parent('label').removeClass('focused');
  }  
);
```

Where focused has been previously defined with the background-color required. You don't need to use a class however, you could just set the colour separately:

```
$(this).parent('label').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Without JavaScript** you can't do that unless both elements have the same parent in DOM tree.
 `element1 + element2` is "successor" selector - it applies rules to every `element2`s that are placed immediately after `element1`. But with CSS you can visually place one element in another without it being it's parent. POC:

```css
label {
  float:left;
  margin-right: -22px;
  padding-right: 22px;
}
input:focus + label {background-color: red;}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label {
  outline:none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 240, 255, 0.4);
  background-color : rgba(0, 240, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input id="contact_form_mail" name="contact_form_mail" type="email" placeholder="Your e-mail address...">
  <label><input id="chkYesIsSubPropofferedSale" type="checkbox"></label>
  <br>
  <input id="chkYesIsSubPropofferedSale" type="checkbox">
  <label>Check</label>
</div>
```